# SQL query formulation

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to edit a database using phpMyAdmin.

The table is 'jos_k2_items' and where 'CatID' = '1616' I need to set all 'created_by' values to '97'.

Im just not sure how I would write that in SQL!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE jos_k2_items set created_by='97'
WHERE CATID = '1616'
```

There is execute sql in phpmyadmin so you can execute this there.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE jos_k2_items SET created_by="97" WHERE CatID="1616"`

That should do what you want